# How delete object in one side at bidirectional relation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, model-view-controller

I want delete relation from one side. Let me explain.

My database looks like this :[image]

I based my repositories on `JPARepository`.

and I have two entities `Team` and `Player`.

`Player` Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "PLAYER")
    public class Player implements Serializable, Comparable<Player>{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id_player;

        @Size(min=3, max=20)
        private String name;
        @Size(min=3, max=20)
        private String surname;
        @Size(min=3, max=20)
        private String position;
        @Min(value=10) 
        private int age;
        @Min(value=1)
        private int number;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_team")
        private Team team;
        //getters and setters
    }
```

...and `Team` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEAM")
public class Team implements Serializable, Comparable<Team>{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id_team;
    @Size(min=4, max=20)
    private String name;
    @Size(min=4, max=20)
    private String city;
    private int goals_hit;
    private int goals_lost;
    private int points;
    private int ranked;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_coach")
    private Coach coach;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_stadium")
    private Stadium stadium;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Player> playerList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<TeamChoosenDate> teamChoosenDateList;
    //getters and setters
}
```

So `Player` contains one relation to `Team` but `Team` contains a `List` of `Players`.

Coach can edit his team and for example he wants delete `Player` from `Team` (relation between `Team` --> `Player`) but not lose the `Player` (because he has relations with other table - `Events`).

**In conclusion:**
Delete `Player` from correct `Team`, but NOT LOSE `Player` object.

**How can I do this ?**

My try: I delete `Player` from `List` but every time when I reload - he comes back... Below method shows how I do this :

```
public void deletePlayerFromTeamPlayerList(Long idTeam, int idPlayer){

    Team team = teamRepository.findOne(idTeam);
    Player playerTmp = playerRepository.findOne( (long) idPlayer);

    List<Player> playerList;

    int indexOfFindedPLayer;


    playerList = team.getPlayerList();

    System.out.println("Before Delete: " + playerList.toString());

    indexOfFindedPLayer = playerList.indexOf(playerTmp);

    if(indexOfFindedPLayer >= 0){
        playerList.remove(indexOfFindedPLayer);

        System.out.println("After Delete: " + playerList.toString());

        team.setPlayerList(playerList);
        teamRepository.save(team);
    }
}
```

But when the element is removed, at `Player` object `id_team` is still the same (ex. id_team = 2)

Thanks for all suggestions!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this more simply by doing the below:

```
public void deletePlayerFromTeam(int idPlayer){
    Player player = //loadPlayer;
    player.setTeam(null);

    playerRepository.save(player);
}
```

You can also achieve this in your original code by setting the player.team to null **and** and by setting cascade on the collection to merge:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
private List<Player> playerList;
```

You should always ensure both sides of the relationship are maintained consistently.

Comment: I was about to comment something like this. Btw, I would add that the database model should be changed to have an additional table/entity to represent the relation between Player/Team, so it would be much better for these types of things.

Comment: `There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement`and in console `Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'id_team' cannot be null`

Comment: `id_team` field type is `int` but maybe I should add some option that allow that field be `null` ?

Comment: Yes, you have not null constraint on player.id_team  in the database. You will obviously need to remove this if you want to keep players with no team.

Comment: Yea awesome! :) It works perfectly! I must change only my method which shows list of players (make condition that `player.getTeam() != null`) and everything is working! THANKS !

Comment: One more question, how set in my Entity (when hibernate auto-update database) to create the field `id_team` was abble to be `null` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use This way for deleting only one side in one to many or many to one relationship.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
//  @JoinColumn(name = "qid")
    @JoinColumn(name = "qid", referencedColumnName = "qid", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "qid"), nullable = false)
    // @JsonIgnore
    @JsonBackReference
    private QueueGroup queueGroup;
```

Here CascadeType is the main thing all the transaction depends on that.